# Device Administration API, allow specific apps to use the camera

Tags: android, android-camera, device-admin, device-policy-manager

We've been working on a few applications in the past few months that are going to be used at work, (small company, apps are not going to be published to the app store). Our employees receive a phone that should only be used in a working environment, and we would like to prevent the user from taking pictures with the device and apps like facebook. This can be done by the Android's Device Admin API, so we will create an additional application to enforce the rule to block the camera from being used. But one of our applications has a feature to take a picture (from documents) and upload them to a server. And with the camera being disabled it's a problem.

My Question: Is it possible to allow certain applications to bypass the camera block? I've done some research but can not seem to find a callback for this feature.

My idea was the following: create a Device Admin application which contains the application id's from our applications (since we made them we know them) So if the Device Admin app receives a broadcast that app XX wants to access the camera and app XX is inside an array of allowed app id's, the device admin app returns a true state (allowing the app to access the camera) and apps that are not in the array will be blocked.

Is this possible and has someone done this before ? It would be nice if someone pointed us in the right direction :). Also i'm sure we are not the only one looking for an answer to this question. So we hope that this post will help people in the future struggling with this problem.

Comment: You can enable and disable the camera at will in your device admin app. You could do so in response to a broadcast. However, while the camera is enabled, any app can access the camera. In theory, your camera app's broadcasts can prevent other foreground apps from accessing the camera. But you aren't goiing to be able to block apps running in the background from using the camera, other than to the extent that your camera might be tying up the camera hardware.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you for your quick response, so technically you can enable the camera from one of our apps by sending a broadcast to the dev. admin app? So the other way around should also be possible ? If our app gets "destroyed", send to background or quit we could disable it with a broadcast aswell ?

Comment: "you can enable the camera from one of our apps by sending a broadcast to the dev. admin app?" -- sure. Have the `BroadcastReceiver` call `setCameraEnabled()` on a `DevicePolicyManager`. "If our app gets "destroyed", send to background or quit we could disable it with a broadcast aswell ? " -- this gets *much* trickier. You can have your camera app send a broadcast when it gets paused, causing your device admin app to disable camera access. Usability of the camera app will decrease, multi-window will be a problem, and there may be ways to kill your process before your UI gets paused.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Once again thank you for your reply. We're going to try to "unlock" the camera for a fixed number of seconds, in order that the user could take a picture and see how that turns out! Thank you for getting us in the right direction.